# How to add ContentVersion data to an outbound email from a Trigger

Tags: email-template, apex-email-service, massemailmessage

So I have the following class:

```
public static void sendmail(String documenttitle)
{
    List<Id> contactids = new List<Id>();
    List<user> con = new List<User>();
    con = [select Id from User where name IN ('User A', 'User B', 'User C', 'User D')];
    for(User u : con)
    {
        contactids.add(u.Id);
    }  


ContentDocument cont = new ContentDocument();


if(documenttitle.contains('Media'))
{
    Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
    mail.setTargetObjectIds(contactids);
    mail.setTemplateId('00AA0000001AaaA');
    mail.saveAsActivity = false;
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
```

}

Which sends out an email to four recipients (Users A-D) when apiece of content with the word "Media" in the title is uploaded.

Now, Is there a way to include things such as:

```
ContentVersion.Title();
ContentVersion.Description();
ContentVersion.ContentUrl();
ContentVersion.OWnerID();
```

etc...

into the body of the email through apex? I can't seem to find a way to access that info directly through the email template...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to do a SOQL query and a Visualforce email template.